# DOMNode::getAttribute with namespace that isn't defined

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-namespaces, dom-node

A project I am working on needs to parse an XML document from a vendor but they provided invalid XML that has attributes with namespaces that aren't declared. `getAttribute($name)` ignores it when I try both `$node->getAttribute('prod:amount')` and `$node->getAttribute('amount')`

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to fake the definition somehow?

**Edit** Providing XML excerpt and PHP.

XML:

```
<order>
    <item id="85127" prod:id="1397" prod:amount="12.99">
        <desc><![CDATA[...]]></desc>
    </item>
    <item id="85128" prod:id="93" prod:amount="24.99">
        <desc><![CDATA[...]]></desc>
    </item>
    ...
</order>
```

PHP:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('URI');
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName("item") as $node) {
    $cost = $node->getAttribute("amount");
    $id = $node->getAttribute("prod:id");
    print_r($cost); //never outputs
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the XML and the code you're using? Have you contacted the vendor to tell them that their XML is invalid?

Comment: The vendor doesn't support their API, its a "convenience" feature. 99% of their customers use their GUI and built-in integration points. The client is insisting that it needs to be added to their sales portal, though.

Comment: The code that you've posted is invalid -- I can pull the amount from the XML, although DOMDocument does throw a hissy fit (aka a load of warnings) about the undeclared namespaces. I'd be somewhat tempted to commit that most heinous of crimes, and add a fake namespace declaration into the XML.

Comment: I get no output, and here is a screenshot of the errors: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfbxo5l2on4z979/xml_prefix_not_defined.PNG?dl=1

Comment: After adding an @ in front of $doc->load() to suppress the warnings it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, that some XML views (Firefox for example) do not show xmlns attributes (namespace definitions). If you don't get an error message (aka the XML is valid) open the source to check for the namespace definitions.

In the source you posted, the prefix of the 'amount' attribute is missing, so it will not display anything.

```
$cost = $node->getAttribute("prod:amount");
```

But it is not a god idea to rely on the namespace prefixes defined in the document. The better way is using the namespace itself.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<order xmlns:prod="urn:products">
    <item id="85127" prod:id="1397" prod:amount="12.99"></item>
    <item id="85128" prod:id="93" prod:amount="24.99"></item>
</order>
XML;

const XMLNS_PROD = 'urn:products';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXml($xml);
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName("item") as $node) {
    $cost = $node->getAttributeNS(XMLNS_PROD, "amount");
    $id = $node->getAttributeNS(XMLNS_PROD, "id");
    var_dump($id, $cost);
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "1397"
string(5) "12.99"
string(2) "93"
string(5) "24.99"
```

So if here really is no namespace definition, then you could "repair" the XML by adding one. This is a workaround, the real solution is to fix the XML at it's source.

```
$xml = str_replace('<order>', '<order xmlns:prod="urn:products">', $xml);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXml($xml);
```